# How to get a list of a repository branches using Python

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am trying to get a list of all the branches available on my repository using Python with this code :

```py
import subprocess

branches = ["All"]
command = "git branch -r"
branch_list = subprocess.check_output(command)

for branch in branch_list:
   print branch
   branches.append[branch]
```

What I want is to have something like :

```py
print branches[0] # is "All"
print branches[1] # is "branch1"
print branches[2] # is "branch2"
etc etc
```

but instead of that I have

```py
print branches[0] # is "All"
print branches[1] # is "b"
print branches[2] # is "r"
print branches[3] # is "a"
print branches[4] # is "n"
print branches[5] # is "c"
print branches[6] # is "h"
etc etc
```

Thank you for your time and your help

Comment: don't name your variable as `list`

Comment: ^ In general, refrain from using reserved keywords and builtins as variable names, as it will cause the builtin to be overwritten with your value, breaking code that expects the builtin to be what it actually is

Comment: I know this is just for he example

Comment: subprocess.check_output returns a (multi-line) string. Iterating on a string give you letters...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a peek at the `check_output` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), it looks like we're getting a blob of bytes back. To make it easier to work with, we can decode it. Then, since `git branch -r` outputs one branch per line, split the string on newlines:

```
branches = subprocess.check_output(command).decode().split('\n')
```

BUT I think there's an even easier way to do it. Every single object in git corresponds to some file under the `.git` directory. In this case, you can find your list of branches in `.git/refs/heads`:

```
import os
branches = os.listdir('.git/refs/heads')
```

---

EDIT (2020/10/13): I've spent some more time with `subprocess` since writing this response and wanted to point out the `text` option (via `subprocess.run`):

> If `encoding` or `errors` are specified, or `text` is true, file objects for stdin, stdout and stderr are opened in text mode using the specified encoding and errors or the `io.TextIOWrapper` default.

This means you could write the `check_output` expression as:

```py
branches = subprocess.check_output(command, text=True).split('\n')
```

leaving encoding and decoding to the system. Whichever you prefer!

Comment: Your solution is working great for me, adding the ```.decode().split('\n')``` was the good way to do, thanks a lot from a python newbie ;)

Comment: For your second solution, I work with mutilple repository so I need ```--git-dir=``` and ```--work-tree=``` to change the repo whenever I want, but thanks for the advice

Comment: "Every single object in git corresponds to some file under the `.git` directory" is false. refs and objects can be packed,

Answer (score 2):

Try `decode`ing it:

```py
stdout = subprocess.check_output('git branch -a'.split())
out = stdout.decode()
branches = [b.strip('* ') for b in out.splitlines()]
print(branches)
```

output:

```
['master', 'second', 'test']
```

Answer (score 0):

For python3,

```
import subprocess

# refs/remotes for remote tracking branches.
# refs/heads for local branches if necessary, and
# refs/tags for tags
cmd = 'git for-each-ref refs/remotes --format="%(refname)"'
status, output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
branches = ["All"]
if status == 0:
    branches += output.split('\n')
print(branches)
```

For python2, replace `subprocess` with `commands`.