# How to interact with Azure devops Repo-Branches using Python

Tags: python, azure-devops

I am trying to establish connection/get project details /push-files/run yaml configuration in Repos-Branches with Azure-Devops using python.

Made some google & got the below code, which modified a few to understand the project ID's/ Last updated time/ description / url / visibility.

```
   from azure.devops.connection import Connection
   from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
   import pprint

   # Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
   personal_access_token = 'YYY'
   organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/XXX'

   # Create a connection to the org
   credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
   connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

   # Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
   core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()

   # Get the first page of projects
   get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()


    index = 0
    while get_projects_response is not None:
        for project in get_projects_response.value:
            print(project)
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.name) 
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.visibility) 
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.url) #https://dev.azure.com/TYU/_apis/projects/TTT'
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.state) #wellformed
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.id) # TYU
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.description) #ABCD
            pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + str(project.last_update_time)) #2020-10-09 09:03:27.467000+00:00
            index += 1
        if get_projects_response.continuation_token is not None and get_projects_response.continuation_token != "":
           # Get the next page of projects
           get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects(continuation_token=get_projects_response.continuation_token)
        else:
           # All projects have been retrieved
           get_projects_response = None
```

Wondering how to get Repos Branch details & push file into Repos folder & execute the file. Any help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the below info with us? 1. Get the repos Branch details, could you please share what information you need here? 2. push file into Repos folder & execute the file, this is the operation on the files in the branch, right?

Comment: Hi, 1. Yes, would like to understand how many branches are in repos & also names of the branches in Repos. 2. And also, Yes, Later need to push some file into any one of the branches in Repos & execute the same file in the respective branch.

Comment: Hi, Would you mind using a power shell script or Git cmd to do this?

Comment: Yes, Am beginner in power shell scripts, pls could you help me with power shell scripts ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @ReachDhruvah, If you have any concern, feel free to share it here, I will still be here to help you solve the issue. By the way, you could also check this [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api), it contains some python sample.

Comment: Finally above doc helped to get repository, branches name but not sure how to upload a file into branches via Rest API. or am i missing anything. pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this ticket [get a list of a repository branches using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905963/how-to-get-a-list-of-a-repository-branches-using-python), I am beginner in python scripts, I am not sure how to use python script to implement this, you could check it, This may help you.

And this is power shell script to Get branch number and list branches name.

```
$connectionToken="{PAT}"
    $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
    $URL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo ID}/refs?filter=heads&api-version=6.1-preview.1"
    $Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get 
    Write-Host "This repo branch number is" $Result.count "and they are " $Result.value.name
```

Result:

[image]

Push file via Git

```
git init
git remote add {Repo URL}
git add {File}
git commit -m "{Commit message}"
git push -u origin {Branch name}
```

In addition, I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa3fuhl1pCE) it contain push file via cmd, please also check it.